# In Koin, when is the viewmodel created and destroyed?

Tags: android, viewmodel, koin

I wonder when the `viewmodel` or `sharedviewmodel` is created and destroyed when it is injected within the activity or fragment.

```kotlin
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { SomeViewModel(get()) }
}
```

**In Activity**

```kotlin
override val viewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModel()
```

**In Fragment**

```kotlin
override val viewModel: SomeViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

When the owner activity is finished, the framework calls the ViewModel objects's onCleared() method so that it can clean up resources.

The most common answer to your question is cleared in the ViewModel onCleared() method.